# PHP - mt_rand function, how to use it to generate a random 20 letter password?

Tags: php, random, passwords

I've used the manual page on `mt_rand()`, but I just don't get how the example makes any sense, I guess this is two parts, what defines the min and max, if `mt_rand(5,15)` can return `1604716014` I suppose its not limited between `5-15`. And how would I regex in some letters to make a password reset generator?

Thanks

Comment: To generate letters, I would have mt_rand generate valid ascii codes and just convert them to letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a little bit of script that I like to use to generate a random `code`:

```
function generateCode( $charSeed ) { // you can use the username as $charSeed
    $seed = "";
    for ( $i = 1; $i <= 8; $i++ ) {
        $seed .= substr( '0123456789abcdef', rand( 0, 15 ), 1 );
    }
    return md5( $seed . $charSeed ) . $seed;
}
```

You may have misread the documentation. `mt_rand(5,15)` or `rand(5,15)` will absolutely generate a random number between 5 and 15!

Comment: I guess I did then, I got confused because of what the output says on this example, http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php#refsect1-function.mt-rand-examples

Comment: I agree. I've always found the PHP manual a bit confusing. I think what they're trying to say is:
`mt_rand()` results in 1604716014
`mt_rand(5,15)` results in 6